# Typo3 crashed after installing extension and now can't access live site or backend: Parse error: syntax error

Tags: typo3, syntax-error, typo3-7.6.x, parse-error, typo3-extensions

As the title says. I was working on my typo3 site and tried installing the mmc_slideshow extension from the typ03 website. After clicking install an error appeared and now i can no longer access the live site. When I try to look at the /typo3 backend it is just the same error. It looks like the site is wiped. Is there anything I can do to get it back? I was able to see the files by looking into /typo3conf but it doesn't give me any editing options. The only thing i can think of is getting in through the hosting server.

Comment: You can connect the server via SSH/SFTP and drop the `typo3conf/ext/mmc_slideshow` directory followed by dropping it from the `typo3conf/PackageStates.php`. Also I'd strongly recommend setting up a local development environment where things like this can be prepared safely.

Comment: That worked! thank you very much. Panic averted! I agree a staging site would be wonderful, I've tried requesting it. those things are up to my bosses though.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the editing of `typo3conf/PackageStates.php`, which Mathias mentioned, you may need cleaning the cache (I don't remember the folder for sure, something like `typo3temp/Cache/Code/`? In doubt you may delete everything from `/typo3temp/`.)

Another option could be the Install-Tool where you might be able to disable failing extensions.